# Python: How to distinguish between inherited methods

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Newbie Python question.  I have a class that inherits from several classes, and some of the specialization classes override some methods from the base class.  In certain cases, I want to call the unspecialized method.  Is this possible?  If so, what's the syntax?

```
class Base(object):
    def Foo(self):
        print "Base.Foo"

    def Bar(self):
        self.Foo()  # Can I force this to call Base.Foo even if Foo has an override?


class Mixin(object):
    def Foo(self):
        print "Mixin.Foo"


class Composite(Mixin, Base):
    pass


x = Composite()
x.Foo()  # executes Mixin.Foo, perfect
x.Bar()  # indirectly executes Mixin.Foo, but I want Base.Foo
```

Comment: `foo`/`bar`?  Why so serious; Python uses `spam`/`eggs`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can specifically make the call you want using the syntax

```
Base.Foo(self)
```

in your case:

```
class Base(object):
    # snipped

    def Bar(self):
        Base.Foo(self)  # this will now call Base.Foo regardless of if a subclass
                        # overrides it

# snipped


x = Composite()
x.Foo()  # executes Mixin.Foo, perfect
x.Bar()  # prints "Base.Foo"
```

This works because Python executes calls to bound methods of the form

```
instance.method(argument)
```

as if they were a call to an unbound method

```
Class.method(instance, argument)
```

so making the call in that form gives you the desired result. Inside the methods, `self` is just the instance that the method was called on, i.e, the implicit first argument (that's explicit as a parameter)

Note however that if a subclass overrides `Bar`, then there's nothing (good) that you can effectively do about it AFAIK. But that's just the way things work in python.

Comment: Thanks!  I think I knew all that, but I overcomplicated it in my head.